Trouble Accessing localhost:8080/graphiql
I am currently building a basic REST API application using Java and SpringBoot. I updated my application.properties file and pom.xml to allow the integration of graphiql/graphql. When I try running my application and using localhost to connect to graphiql. I am not able to access it and gives me 404 status not found. I also tried graphql and the same result happened: 404. Note: I have a mutator and resolver that uses the interface of GraphQLMutationResolver and GraphQLQueryResolver respectively. I will also attach my github repo to this project for more insight. Note: service, web, static and templates directory are marked excluded so technically they are not part of the project when it's being run.
1st Image: is the description of how the error appears
2nd Image: Application.properties
3rd Image: when running localhost:8080/graphiql
Project Repo: Link




Your application isn't exposing any graphql endpoint, thus you are seeing the error.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
</dependency>

Add the above dependency in your pom.xml.
Also in your data-model application.graphqls replace countApplications: Long! with countApplications: Int!. You can check and define the available scalars and add them separately to your schema.
